# in MKMapkit how to get the current location detail in textfield or tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6, iphone-5

```
RootViewController *objYourViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionPush;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objYourViewController animated:YES];
```

This is used to point the current location. Now i want to get the current location detail in textfield or tableview so please help me if any one know.

Answer (score 1):

I had use below code..

First Add `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate` in `.h` file..

after create object of `MKReverseGeocoder` in `.h` file like belolow..

```
MKReverseGeocoder *mkReverseGeocoder;
```

and then use it like bellow on your `UIButton` Action event

```
-(IBAction)btnFindMe_Clicked:(id)sender{
    if(mkReverseGeocoder)
    {
        [mkReverseGeocoder autorelease];
    }
    
    mkReverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[currLocation coordinate]];
    
    [mkReverseGeocoder setDelegate:self];
    [mkReverseGeocoder start];
}
```

and this bellow methods are delegate methods of `MKReverseGeocoder`

```
//mkreversegeocoder protocol methods

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [appDelegate hideLoadingView];
    UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Try Again After Sometime" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alt show];
    [alt release];
//    NSLog(@"\n\n Error is %@",[error description]);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{

    [appDelegate hideLoadingView];
    NSLog(@"\n\n Address Dict : %@",[[placemark addressDictionary] description]);
    txtCity.text=[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"City"];
    txtState.text=[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"State"];
    txtAddress1.text=[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"Street"];
    txtAddress2.text=[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"SubLocality"];
    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[gpsTextView addressDictionary] description], ];
}
```

Also See this link with example but its another code.. above is my custom code... [how-to-get-current-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone/](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/miscellaneous/how-to-get-current-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone/)

Comment: @vishnu see this link also with tutorial .. http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/miscellaneous/how-to-get-current-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone/ :)

Comment: paras joshi. can u pls help me.i can't fetch the current location...i need current location as default value in tableview.