# ios: What is the efficient and recommended way to reverse geocode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, reverse-geocoding

I am to reverse Geo Code Latitude and Longitude of some location and want to get address  of that location. I have done it through google web service but it takes time.
I want to know if there is some other good and efficient approach.

Currently calling this service,

```
NSString * getAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%@,%@&sensor=true",Lattitude,Longitude];
```

Comment: see my answer something like your requirement from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009729/locationmanager-avoid-null-string-in-a-label/16009810#16009810

Comment: see my another answer for Location detail from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682595/in-mkmapkit-how-to-get-the-current-location-detail-in-textfield-or-tableview/15682757#15682757

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `CLGeocoder`:

```
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){
    CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
    NSLog(@"Found %@", placemark.name);
}];
```

This will still take time though, since both methods use web services to convert lat / long into a place

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use this in production code. This will crash the app if there is an error and placemarks is either NULL or empty.

Answer (score 5):

Try This code .

```
geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler:

     //Getting Human readable Address from Lat long,,,

     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
         //Get nearby address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            //String to hold address
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
            //Print the location to console
         NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
     }];
```

Comment: NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "]; exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `GLGeocoder`. Specifically `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apple's `CLGeocoder` (part of CoreLocation). Specifically, the `– reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` method which will return a dictionary of address data for the given coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/), or, if just want something to copy quickly: NSArray *addressOutput;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
    //assumes these instance variables

```
// Reverse Geocoding
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[placemarks count]];
        for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {
            [tempArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                  placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                  placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                  placemark.administrativeArea,
                                  placemark.country]];
        }
        addressOutput = [tempArray copy];
    }
    else {
        addressOutput = nil;
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}];
```

Based off the code in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you to not want to use google API, try this code - basically transforms latitude and longitude inputs into ZIPs (can be adjusted to adresses).

```
pip install uszipcode

# Import packages
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
from uszipcode import Zipcode
import numpy as np

#define zipcode search function
def get_zipcode(lat, lon):
    result = search.by_coordinates(lat = lat, lng = lon, returns = 1)
    return result[0].zipcode

#load columns from dataframe
lat = df_shooting['Latitude']
lon = df_shooting['Longitude']

#define latitude/longitude for function
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':lat, 'lon':lon})

#add new column with generated zip-code
df['zipcode'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_zipcode(x.lat,x.lon), axis=1)

#print result
print(df)

#(optional) save as csv
#df.to_csv(r'zip_codes.csv')
```